# Is the return keyword needed for tail recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

we're learning about recursion in school.

From what I've read online, you can optimize recursive functions by making the recursive step to be the last thing the function does.

But is the return keyword needed? Even for void functions?

```
void insert(Node<T>*& n, T value) 
{
    if (n == nullptr)
    {
        n = new Node<T>(value);
        return;
    }
    else if (value < n->get_value())
    {
        Node<T>* left = n->get_left();
        return insert(left, value);
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T>* right = n->get_right();
        return insert(right, value);
    }
}
```

Would this still be tail recursion without the return keyword?
Specifically in the `else if`, because without it, it would "no longer be the last thing the functions does".

Comment: [Void functions are created and used just like value-returning functions except they do not return a value after the function executes](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~cop3014p/lectures/ch7/index.html).

Comment: Seems like `n` needs to be a reference to a pointer if you want `n = new Node<T>(value);` to do something useful.

Comment: Based on @PeterBecker's observation, I guess I should ask:
Does the code you typed in even compile? Without brackets around the body of the if clause, I'm thinking it would not.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.

Comment: @AnneGunn it's ok, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically in the else if, because without it, it would "no longer be the last thing the functions does".

That is not true.

The `insert` call is, *in all cases* except when `n == nullptr`, the last thing the function does.

Adding a redundant `return` statement doesn't change that.

This:

```
void bar() {}

void foo()
{
    return bar();
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
void bar() {}

void foo()
{
   bar();
   return;
}
```

Or this:

```
void bar() {}

void foo()
{
   bar();
}
```

In absolutely every way.

In fact, the only reason we're *allowed* to do this at all, in a function returning `void` (remember, you're not actually returning any value here!), is to make implementing templates a bit easier.

And, in all of those examples, the compiler does not need to set up a fresh stack frame for the call to `bar()`. In the case of a recursive function, that gives you *tail recursion*.

Comment: So it qualifies as tail recursion even in the `if else`?

Comment: because I get what you're saying about returning, but you're examples only show at the end of a function. Not inside an `if`, with more code after it

Comment: @user644361 There is not "more code after it". On every possible path through your program, the recursive call to `insert` is the last thing to happen. The compiler should be able to tell that all it needs to do is select the appropriate argument. But you can look at the assembly to see what your compiler does. Either way, this has nothing to do with `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Those returns are not doing anything in your code.

Simply remove the one "return;" line entirely.

Take the  return off of the other two lines.

I'm no expert on tail recursion but I do know your code does the same thing and is simpler without the returns in it.

Comment: The `return` in the `if` and `else if` blocks stops the program from going further

Comment: @user644361 — the returns don’t stop the **program**; they stop the **function** from doing anything more. But this particular function doesn’t do anything more anyway, so the returns really don’t do anything here. (Assuming that the two lines following the `if` we’re supposed to be inside curly braces)

Comment: @user644361 If there were other lines in any of the if, else-if, or else clauses, a return might be of some value. As it is, execution will travel into exactly one of those clauses and then, after the return from the recursion, fall to the bottom of the function. No return needed to alter execution path.

Comment: @PeteBecker Nice catch! I missed that.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah, I meant the function... The return keyword in the `else if` block **could** be making the function tail recursion. That's what I'm asking

Answer (score 2):

In your code all three `return`s do nothing and can be removed.

If a function returns `void`, then `return` is used *only* for terminating the function early. In your code there is nothing after all those `return`s, so they are superfluous.

---

On the other hand, if a function returns non-`void`, then it *has* to terminate via `return` (or exceptions or `std::exit` and so on). If control reaches the closing `}` of such a function, the behavior is undefined.

`main()` is an exception to this rule, reaching the closing `}` of `main()` automatically does `return 0;`.

---

Also, as @RetiredNinja said, *"n needs to be a reference to a pointer"*. Otherwise the changes you make to `n` are discarded, and the memory allocated via `new` is leaked.